# How to add some space for my button layout?

Tags: html, css

--How would I go about adding padding to the buttons?--The animations work but adding some space between them seems to be the issue-- I would still like all my buttons being on the same line but just spaced out a bit more--Still somewhat new at this so I appreciate the help--

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: .1px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #9DDAC6;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #a22274;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #a22274;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p align="center">

  <button><a href="https://twitter.com/TheOnlyDecipher">Twitter page</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Information</a></button>

  <button> <a href="points.html">Points of Interest</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Learning.html">Learning notes</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Beebs.html">Notes for Wife</a></button>


  <br><br>
</p>
```

Comment: Instead of using p, use a div with flex property

Comment: I think you're looking for margin https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code seem to be what I was looking for:

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: .1px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #3EDBF0;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #a22274;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #a22274;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <button><a href="https://twitter.com/TheOnlyDecipher">Twitter page</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Information</a></button>

  <button> <a href="points.html">Points of Interest</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Learning.html">Learning notes</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Beebs.html">Notes for Wife</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Reference.html">Reference</a></button>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this, but probably the easiest is adding margin to the left and right. You may also want to style your button size with something more responsive for different size screens.

Just add this to your button style:

```
button {
min-width: 8em;
height: 2em;
font-size: 16;
cursor: pointer;
letter-spacing: .1px;
outline: none;
border: none;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f7f7f7;
background-color: #9DDAC6;
color: #000;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
**margin: 0 2%;**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```css
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  /* padding to avoid scale/shadow clipping. */
  padding: 1em;
}

.buttons button {
  /* layout control */
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0.35em 0.4em;
  
  /* shared between states */
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  min-width: 8em;
  font-size: 1em;
  
  /* state specifc */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #a17979;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background-color: #e06cb5;
  
  /* transition */
  transition-property: background-color, border-radius, box-shadow, transform;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.buttons button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0px #b8b0b0;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.buttons button:active {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.buttons button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.buttons button:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a22274;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button><a href="https://twitter.com/TheOnlyDecipher">Twitter page</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Information</a></button>

  <button> <a href="points.html">Points of Interest</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Learning.html">Learning notes</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Beebs.html">Notes for Wife</a></button>
</div>
```

I've grouped the properties so that you can spot which ones control the layout from the others.

Note that to avoid the buttons shifting when you hover with the mouse, you must avoid modifying the **size** of the properties you specify (for example: font size or thickness, border thickness, etc.).

Since transformations do not change the page layout you have to make sure that the `div` wrapping the buttons has enough padding to prevent them from being cropped. The same goes for the margins that have been specified in the buttons.

Note about the `em`s from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units):

> To recap, the em unit means "my parent element's font-size" in the
> case of typography. The `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` with a class of
> ems take their sizing from their parent. So each successive level of
> nesting gets progressively larger, as each has its font size set to
> 1.3em — 1.3 times its parent's font size.

Obviously `em`s should not be used indiscriminately in all properties, but generally it gives you the possibility to create a certain layout style that scales automatically by simply changing the font size, avoiding having to write rules for each scale.

Regarding transitions: try to specify only the properties that actually need them in order to have more control over the result. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property):

> Note: The set of properties that can be animated is subject to change.
> As such, you should avoid including any properties in the list that
> don't currently animate, as someday they might, causing unexpected
> results.

I left out forcing all the buttons in a single row because, if you add more in the future or change device (smartphone, tablet, pc), you may see them automatically go to multiple lines.

One last note: the `inline` or `inline-block` elements also take into account the newlines and spaces present in the HTML source code. If you want to control the layout correctly you **don't have to insert lines or wrap** between buttons, otherwise you will see extra space between them that doesn't depend on CSS rules.

Comment: Wow that was amazing thank you so much for your help

Comment: @TheOnlyDecipher Glad to be helpful, please mark the answer as accepted if you think it met all of your requirements.